# Determinant of special partitioned matrix in terms of submatrix determinants

Tags: matrices, determinant, symmetry

I have a few determinant-related questions that I've been struggling with for at least a few days. I couldn't see a similar question on here. So, here it is:

I wrote my own electromagnetics moment method solver to calculate eigenvalues (cutoff frequencies) of a certain waveguide. It works fine, but now I want to try to take advantage of physical symmetry of the structure that I'm investigating. The matrix whose determinant is of interest is called the impedance matrix, usually denoted as $Z,$ which is an $N\times N$ complex matrix.

What we're interested in is the smallest eigenvalue of $Z.$ When the smallest eigenvalue is zero (or close to it), that gives me the cutoff frequency (in other words, I'm trying to find where $\det(Z)=0$). By using one plane of symmetry, it can be shown that the impedance matrix can be written as:

$$
Z =  \left[\begin{array}{cc}
Z_{1} & Z_{2}\\
Z_{2}^{R} & Z_{1}^{R}
\end{array}\right]
$$
where $Z_1^R$ and $Z_2^R$ are reversed square matrices, obtained from $Z_1$ and $Z_2,$ respectively, by reversing the order of both rows and columns. According to the reference I'm using ("Field computation by moment methods" by Harrington), the determinant of $Z$ is given by
$$
\det(Z) = \det(Z_1+Z_2)\times\det(Z_1-Z_2)
$$
which I have confirmed numerically in my case. **My first question:** Why is this true? I refreshed my linear algebra by going through bunch of materials online and offline, but could not come up with anything yet explaining this.

*Side note 1:* $Z_1 + Z_2$ is called the even-mode impedance matrix, $Z_1 - Z_2$ is called the odd-mode impedance matrix. Depending on whether the waveguide mode is even or odd, one or the other gives the eigenvalue that I'm interested in.

*Side note 2:* While this is probably not true in general, in the specific problem that I'm solving it so happens that $Z_1 = Z_1^R$ and $Z_2 = Z_2^R.$

Moving on, I can actually divide things up further to speed up my calculations because my geometry has not one, but two planes of symmetry. So, I can actually write the impedance matrix as follows
$$
Z = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
\underset{Z_{1}}{\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{cc}
Z_{11} & Z_{12}\\
Z_{12}^{R} & Z_{11}^{R}
\end{array}\right]}} & \underset{Z_{2}}{\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{cc}
Z_{21} & Z_{22}\\
Z_{22}^{R} & Z_{21}^{R}
\end{array}\right]}}\\
Z_{2}^{R} & Z_{1}^{R}
\end{array}\right]
$$
which means I can potentially deal with $\frac{N}{4} \times \frac{N}{4}$ matrices. Note that in this case $Z_{ij} \neq Z_{ij}^R$ for $i,j=1,2.$

**My second question:** I'd like to find a way that involves calculating determinants of $Z_{11},\;Z_{12},\;Z_{21},\;Z_{22}$ (or combinations thereof) such that when it is minimized, the determinant of $Z$ is also minimized. My hope is if I figure out the answer to my first question, I can extend it to this specific case. For instance, I calculate the following:
$$
\det(Z_{11}+Z_{21}+Z_{12}+Z_{22}) \times \det(Z_{11}+Z_{21}-Z_{12}-Z_{22})
$$
and it is actually pretty close to $\det(Z_1+Z_2).$ By pretty close, I mean $\det(Z_1+Z_2) = 1.152-j0.2717$ versus the above gives $1.131-j0.2724.$ Similarly for $\det(Z_1-Z_2).$ However, "pretty close" does not give me a whole lot of confidence.

Do you have any comments, suggestions, pointers to literature on this?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: As for your first question: Every square matrix $A$ satisfies $A^R = W A W$, where $W$ is the matrix whose anti-diagonal is filled with $1$'s and whose all other entries are $0$. Notice that $W^2 = 1$. Now, any square matrices $A$ and $B$ satisfy $\left( \begin{matrix} A & B \\ B^R & A^R \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} A & B \\ WBW & WAW \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & W \end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} A & BW \\ BW & A \end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & W \end{matrix} \right) $. So now ...

Comment: ... it remains to prove that $\det \left( \begin{matrix} A & BW \\ BW & A \end{matrix} \right) = \det\left(A + B\right) \det\left(A - B\right)$. But I think this is not quite true, and instead it should be $\det \left( \begin{matrix} A & C \\ C & A \end{matrix} \right) = \det\left(A + C\right) \det\left(A - C\right)$, where $C = BW$. This is a fairly well-known fact which you can prove (if $2$ is invertible) by ...

Comment: ... the identity $\left( \begin{matrix} A & C \\ C & A \end{matrix} \right) = \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} A-C & 0 \\ 0 & A+C \end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$.

Comment: Darij- thanks a lot, this clears up my first question! I'll see how far I can go using this to answer my second question